# Как получить ВСЕ данные о видео файле ? (битрейт, формат, кодеки и т.д.)

Tags: c#, видео

Есть возможность такое реализовать ? Что для этого необходимо и какими средствами реализовывать?

Comment: считать заголовок этого видео-файла, заголовки разных видео-форматов могут быть записаны поразному! Вам нужно знать структуру формата звголовка видео файла!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй использовать [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/)

На [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215185/getting-length-of-video?answertab=votes#tab-top) есть пример как получить битрейт и разрешение.